# GWT compilation fails after upgrading sdk from gwt2.5.1 to gwt2.6.1

Tags: gwt, sdk, guava, mgwt

I'm developing a mobile app using gwt and mgwt. Currently I'm using gwt2.5.1 and mgwt1.1.2, I want to upgrade my gwt sdk to gwt2.6.1. In this process I'm getting error at my project compilation time. here is the error description ...

```
[ERROR] Unexpected internal compiler error
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gwt.thirdparty.guava.common.io.Files.hash(Ljava/io/File;Lcom/google/gwt/thirdparty/guava/common/hash/HashFunction;)Lcom/google/gwt/thirdparty/guava/common/hash/HashCode;
 at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCache.computePersistentCacheFilenamePrefix(PersistentUnitCache.java:470)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCache.<clinit>(PersistentUnitCache.java:114)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.UnitCacheFactory.get(UnitCacheFactory.java:59)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.init(CompilationStateBuilder.java:449)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:151)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:132)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:99)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:55)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:50)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:106)
```

I pulled the latest gwt sdk from here. http://www.gwtproject.org/versions.html
I checked gwt-dev.jar and gwt-user.jar , both are from gwt2.6.1 library. 
I event tried by placing the guava-gwt.jar and guava-r09.jar in my classpath.But still getting same. I have no idea on root cause of this error. Please help me on this.

thanks,

Arun Kumar

Answer (score 2):

1. Find `com.google.gwt.thirdparty.guava` import in your code and delete it. Replace it with the import from the latest guava file.
2. Always use the [latest version](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). Currently, it's guava's 18th release.

Answer (score 1):

this arrive when you change the gwt version and skip repleacing gwt servlet jars, 
in my case i upgrad from 2.5.1 to 2.7.0, and i have forgotten to repleace the old jar file in WEB-INF/lib (gwt-servlet.jar and gwt-servlet-dep.jar), you must repleace those jar and then that works again like old time buth with a new version

Comment: This fixed my problem at least. I hadn't updated all the gwt-*.jar files only the servlet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clean the unit cache when changing GWT version. By default it's a `.gwt-unitcache` folder next to your *war* folder (configurable *via* system properties, or depending on your build tool: e.g. the `gwt-maven-plugin` has properties to configure the persistent unit-cache dir)

Comment: I'm no where finding the .gwt-unitcache folder in my project. where could I see it. I'm using eclipse

Comment: Just search. It should be directly in your project output folder (target/bin), as defined in your eclipse project properties...